# No texmaker in ubuntu software centre

Tags: software-installation, updates, software-center

I have installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS in my laptop.

But the problem is there is no texmaker in the ubuntu software centre.

I tried to install it using "sudo apt get install texmaker".

But it said no package found.

It is surprising to find there is no texmaker/texlive in the software centre.

What should I do?I badly need texmaker for my presentation .

Comment: It's `sudo apt-get install texmaker`.

Comment: @kashish I did it but that does not help

Comment: have you installed the updates?

Comment: first update `sudo apt-get update` then try
`sudo apt-get install texmaker`

Answer (score 0):

No, its available.
first update `sudo apt-get update` then try `sudo apt-get install texmaker`

If still doesn't work, then try below
http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/xenial/universe/t/texmaker/install/index.html